# How to find the values that can add up to the closest given value in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: sql, pyspark

I need to find all the values from Weight_val column that can sum up to the closest value in closest_val column. Then when values are found mark them with YES or NO. YES for values that  can sum up to the closest value.

Example:

| ID | Weight_val | closest_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 134211 | 3.9 | 5 |
| 134211 | 21 | 5 |
| 134211 | 1.5 | 5 |
| 134211 | 3.3 | 5 |
| 434217 | 15 | 19 |
| 434217 | 40 | 19 |
| 434217 | 2.1 | 19 |
| 535551 | 3.1 | 18 |
| 535551 | 7.3 | 18 |
| 535551 | 12 | 18 |

Expected Dataframe:

| ID | Weight_val | closest_val | closest_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 134211 | 3.9 | 5 | NO |
| 134211 | 21 | 5 | NO |
| 134211 | 1.5 | 5 | YES |
| 134211 | 3.3 | 5 | YES |
| 434217 | 15 | 19 | YES |
| 434217 | 40 | 19 | NO |
| 434217 | 2.1 | 19 | YES |
| 535551 | 3.1 | 18 | NO |
| 535551 | 7.3 | 18 | YES |
| 535551 | 12 | 18 | YES |

Sincerely I will appreciate any help.

Comment: close? how close is close here?

Comment: If are no values that are  not very close than all the records for that particular ID should be marked with NO